# Running ArcGIS Server rather than ArcGIS Desktop extensions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server

What the advantage of running ArcGIS Server extensions instead of running the same desktop extension?

Comment: Just as with running ArcGIS Server vs ArcGIS Desktop, they are for different purposes. Use Server for the web (ideally suited for smaller tasks which can be run from any web browser), and Desktop for the desktop (where you can perform more intensive analysis using large datasets).

Comment: @StephenLead I think that would suffice as an answer on this one (which from its brevity looks like it could be homework).

Comment: I wish this were for a class, unfortunately I'm supposed to be figuring out the best architecture for my organization.  I guess my real question would be if we are running an extension on the desktop for our analyst do we need to run the same extension on the server. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @GISJoe can you give more information on what you need to do on the server? It'll really depend on how much functionality the web users need - there's no hard-and-fast rule

Comment: There are better ways to learn about [ArcGIS architecture and deployment options](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/System_Design_Strategies_Preface) than asking what now appears to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) question. Your root question is complex, but I think you simplified this question too much to gain from the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as with running ArcGIS Server vs ArcGIS Desktop, they are for different purposes.

Use Server for the web (ideally suited for smaller tasks which can be run from any web browser), and Desktop for the desktop (where you can perform more intensive analysis using large datasets).